# CSS - Crisp boundaries for linear gradient

Tags: html, css

I am using linear gradient to generate two sections of a div with a trapezium-like border. I am not able to get a crisp boundary between the two colors, I get a very narrow region of gradient - I have been able to reduce it, but I haven't been able to reduce it completely.

This is the code I have used:

```css
.buyers-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* ff3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(49%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(50%, #197f88), color-stop(100%, #197f88));
  /* safari4+,chrome */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* ie10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(113deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* w3c */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#197f88', GradientType=1);
  /* ie6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="buyers-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of the gradient produces a step of 1% between `#ffffff`and `#197f88`. Change this from

```
background: linear-gradient(113deg, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 49%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
```

to

```
background: linear-gradient(113deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
```

and you get crisp boundaries (but the angle is rather suboptimal):

```css
.buyers-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* ff3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(50%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(50%, #197f88), color-stop(100%, #197f88));
  /* safari4+,chrome */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(337deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* ie10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(113deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #197f88 50%, #197f88 100%);
  /* w3c */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#197f88', GradientType=1);
  /* ie6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="buyers-div"></div>
```

On [A Collection of Separator Styles](https://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/) there you can see many different and sharp separator styles. May it's helpful for your approach.

Comment: you're right, but in Google Chrome the problem is still present. For example, this fiddle has problems only on Google Chrome: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/rk5jgvpt/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution which uses position relative/absolute and Before pseudo-element. Here it's:

```
//HMTL(PUG)
.buyers-div

CSS(SASS)
.buyers-div
  position:relative
  width: 100%
  height: 500px
  background-color: #197f88
  overflow: hidden
  &:before
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    width: 100%
    height: 500px
    background-color: white
    left: -50%
    transform: skew(-45deg)
```

Check the [SOLUTION](https://codepen.io/T04435/pen/RVYPvB)

THANKS, T04435

Comment: @Roberrrt have you look at the original and compare?  it looks crispy to me.